# A game of checkmarks and crosses - who can get a set number of checkmarks first

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This is a question about a game. I have an empty grid of infinite length, two columns `A` and `B` as well as two numbers `a` and `b` with `a + b = 1`. At every step in the game two random numbers `x` and `y` between 0 and 1 are generated. When `x` is smaller or equal to `a` I put a checkmark in column `A`, otherwise I put a cross there. If `y` is smaller or equal to `b` I'll put a checkmark in `B`, a cross otherwise.

The winner of the game is the first person to reach a set number of checkmarks, `Z`.

An example of a game would be `a = 0.6`, `b = 0.4`, `Z = 5`

```
A: ✓ x ✓ x x ✓ ✓ x ✓ |
B: x ✓ x x ✓ x ✓ x x |
```

`A` won in this game, because it reached 5 checkmarks first. (A had an advantage due to `a = 0.6`

I want to be able to calculate the probability of `A` or `B` winning.

I have already figured out, that it if `a = 0.6` and `b = 0.4`, player `A` is more likely to win. I have also figured out, that the larger `Z` is (the number of checkmarks required to win) the more reliable the prediction will be.

Comment: The number of trials for each player to reach $5$ checkmarks follow a negative binomial distribution. So you are computing $\Pr\{A < B\}$ for the probability of $A$ winning this game, and etc.